# Pagination in jquery data table destroy partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatable

I have table that contains data and links that open partial view with related data. I use jquery datatable, when I'm on first page everything works fine, but if I go to the next pages and cliked link I dont have beauty partial view, page return only source code from partial view file and skips _Layout.cshtml. 
What should I do to make the code work correctly?

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult KsiazkiZlecenia(int zlecKompletID, string magazynID)
    {
        SystemMagazynowy ksiazki = new SystemMagazynowy();
        var listaksiazek = ksiazki.PobierzInfoKsiazek(zlecKompletID, magazynID);
        ViewBag.ksiazki = listaksiazek;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Link:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Książki", "KsiazkiZlecenia", new { zlecKompletID = item.ZlecKompletID, magazynID = ViewBag.MagazynID }, new { @data_modal = "" })
```

Comment: in first page you have render partial view but in other call in ajax it return as a html string you need replace or add that partial view html string into area like $("div").append(response).

Comment: Hi Krystian Nowak do you mind just giving a little bit more information? How do you load the second page?

Comment: I tried to load whole page with partial view code, but when I try to run code, pagination buttons doesn't work, how to do it in ajax?

Comment: I load second page using jquery datatable